# What are spec/requests good for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, integration-testing

I use RSpec to test my lovely little web app. For integration tests I use Steak. When using Rails generators (yep, I know that this is not the Zen way of doing TDD) there are also some files in spec/requests generated. As stated on [link text](http://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) it is something similiar to integration test (but I couldn't find much more info).

Are those request specs still recommended when using something like Steak and Cucumber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you need and want. The goal of testing is to prove that your app works **once**, not twice or more times.

I personally write rspec tests for models and helpers. I use cucumber to test that my views and controllers are working the way I expect them to. With this I can prove that my entire app works as I expect it to, so no, I don't use `spec/requests`.

Occasionally I do use `spec/requests` to test APIs, but you can do that with cucumber as well.

Some don't like the BDD-way cucumber works and stick with `spec/requests`. In the end it's all a matter of taste.